# Indexing rows which meet inequalities or have missing values in R

Tags: r

Note, I am programming in a validated environment which hasn't verified packages such as `dplyr` or `data.table`. However, I am often performing comparisons with dates where the compare date is missing if the event hasn't yet occurred, and in that case I would like to keep the records. The standard solution is too verbose to be very readable:

`newdf <- subset(olddf, scandt <= quitdt | is.na(quitdt))`

It becomes cumbersome when 2 or more dates are being compared with `&` and so the `|` arguments need to be encapsulated in parens. Is there a known solution other than a custom function?

Reproducible example (HAVE):

```
val <- data.frame(
  subj=c('a', 'a', 'b'),
  scandt=as.Date(c('2020-01-01', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01')),
  quitdt=as.Date(c('2020-05-01', '2020-05-01', NA))
  )

subset(val, scandt < quitdt)
```

(GET):

```
> subset(val, scandt < quitdt)
  subj     scandt     quitdt
1    a 2020-01-01 2020-05-01
```

(WANT):

```
> subset(val, scandt < quitdt | is.na(quitdt)) ## one function
  subj     scandt     quitdt
1    a 2020-01-01 2020-05-01
3    b 2020-10-01       <NA>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you had a reproducible example. There are many iteration tools you could use like the apply functions, `Map`, or `Reduce`.

Comment: Lumping alternatives with `any` or similar might save some parentheses.

Comment: With two dates I find it readable, can you post an more complicated example, one you find not very readable?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own [infix function](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html?q=infix#infix-functions). Something like this gets you what you're looking for I think.

```r
val <- data.frame(
  subj=c('a', 'a', 'b'),
  scandt=as.Date(c('2020-01-01', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01')),
  quitdt=as.Date(c('2020-05-01', '2020-05-01', NA))
)

 `%<na%` <- function(left, right) { left < right | is.na(right)}
 
 subset(val, scandt %<na% quitdt)
#>   subj     scandt     quitdt
#> 1    a 2020-01-01 2020-05-01
#> 3    b 2020-10-01       <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>